# missing *.lib file after build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

Hi i wanted to use external library in my project so i downloaded sourcode from https://code.google.com/p/inih/ and i compiled it using Microsoft walkthrough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

```
 Build started 16/01/2015 10:30:39.1>Project "c:\...\Projects\inihlib\inihlib\inihlib.vcxproj" on node 2 (Build target(s)).
 1>ClCompile:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /sdl /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _LIB /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt ...\INIReader.cpp
 INIReader.cpp
 Lib: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\Lib.exe /OUT:"c:\...\Projects\inihlib\Release\inihlib.lib" /NOLOGO /LTCG Release\INIReader.obj
     inihlib.vcxproj -> c:\...\Projects\inihlib\Release\inihlib.lib
 1>Done Building Project "c:\...\Projects\inihlib\inihlib\inihlib.vcxproj" (Build target(s)).
Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.46
```

It looks like inihlib.lib should be in release folder but instead ive got only inih.obj and log file. What im doing wrong any ideas?

Comment: You might be looking in the wrong folder, you could be looking in c:\...\Projects\inihlib\inihlib\Release instead of c:\...\Projects\inihlib\Release?

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. Im ashamed now :P

Comment: The only reason I know is because I have made the same mistake so join the club.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was answered by Shane; issue was simply looking in the wrong folder.

> You might be looking in the wrong folder, you could be looking in c:...\Projects\inihlib\inihlib\Release 
>   instead of 
>   c:...\Projects\inihlib\Release? –  Shane Haw 1 hour ago

Just copy-pasting this for people who come looking for an accepted answer.